# How to implement Ajax File Upload in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, ajax, file-upload

I have a custom form and there I'm using the default file attachment input type but I want the form uploading as a ajax.

I have followed many tutorials but can't find the appropriate solution.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hi @Tim can you share some code ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Yes, please share your code here.

Comment: @AttilaNaghi I have referred this link which suits my requirement, https://www.ytsolution.in/php-ajax-file-upload-with-progress-bar-upload-file-using-ajax/ but how can I implement this in Magento 2. Please guide